# Accessing a relational database using spring jpa/vaadin

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a database setup in mysql with two tables:

**stock_info**

[image: stock_info table]

**stock_price_data:**

[image: stock_price_data table]

The primary key for the first table is set as 'Ticker' and the foreign key of the second one refers to 'Ticker' from the first table also, representing a one to many relationship.

I am trying to access this data within a vaadin web app using spring data. I have attempted to pull all the data from the tables using services, repositories and two entities which extend from an `AbstractEntity`. I am receiving the following errors when I run however:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stockPriceRepository' defined in com.stockmachine.v2.backend.repository.StockPriceRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is ...
```

It is clearly something to do with my referencing/ mapping of the one-to many relationship, but after some googling I still cannot find a solution.

These are my entity classes:

```
package com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table (name="stock_info")
public class Stock extends AbstractEntity implements Cloneable {
    //@Id
    //private String Ticker;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Ticker")
    //private StockPrice stockPrice;
    
    private String Region;

    private String Sector;
    
    private String Industry;
    
    private String Type;
    
    /*public String getTicker() {
        return Ticker;
    }
    public void setTicker(String ticker) {
        Ticker = ticker;
    }*/
    
    public String getRegion() {
        return Region;
    }
    public void setRegion(String region) {
        Region = region;
    }
    public String getSector() {
        return Sector;
    }
    public void setSector(String sector) {
        Sector = sector;
    }
    public String getIndustry() {
        return Industry;
    }
    public void setIndustry(String industry) {
        Industry = industry;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        Type = type;
    }
    
    

}
```

```
package com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
@Entity
@Table(name="stock_price_data")
public class StockPrice extends AbstractEntity  {
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Stock.class, mappedBy="stock", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="Ticker")
    
    
    private double Price;

    private double open_price;

    private double close_price;

    private double volume;
    
    private double relative_strength;
    
    private double ma30;
    
    private double ma7;
    
    private double ma365;
    
    private String date_time;
        
        

    public double getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        Price = price;
    }

    public double getOpen_price() {
        return open_price;
    }

    public void setOpen_price(double open_price) {
        this.open_price = open_price;
    }

    public double getClose_price() {
        return close_price;
    }

    public void setClose_price(double close_price) {
        this.close_price = close_price;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(double volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public double getRelative_strength() {
        return relative_strength;
    }

    public void setRelative_strength(double relative_strength) {
        this.relative_strength = relative_strength;
    }

    public double getMa30() {
        return ma30;
    }

    public void setMa30(double ma30) {
        this.ma30 = ma30;
    }

    public double getMa7() {
        return ma7;
    }

    public void setMa7(double ma7) {
        this.ma7 = ma7;
    }

    public double getMa365() {
        return ma365;
    }

    public void setMa365(double ma365) {
        this.ma365 = ma365;
    }

    public String getDate_time() {
        return date_time;
    }

    public void setDate_time(String date_time) {
        this.date_time = date_time;
    }

        


        
        
}
```

```
package com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    
  @Id
  private String Ticker;

public String getTicker() {
   return Ticker;
  }

  public boolean isPersisted() {
    return Ticker != null;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    if (getTicker() != null) {
      return getTicker().hashCode();
    }
    return super.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
   }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    AbstractEntity other = (AbstractEntity) obj;
 if (getTicker() == null || other.getTicker() == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return getTicker().equals(other.getTicker());
  }
  
}
```

## Edit

---

Thanks to the suggestions I have decided to remove the Abstract entity altogether and have changed the entity classes as follows:

```
public class Stock implements Cloneable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="stock", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Id
    private List<StockPrice> Ticker;
    private String Price;
    ...
     
    public List<StockPrice> getTicker() {
        return Ticker;
    }
    public void setTicker(List<StockPrice> ticker) {
        Ticker = ticker;
    }
```

yet I am still getting the same (or similar) error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stockRepository' defined in com.stockmachine.v2.backend.repository.StockRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity.StockPrice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.stockmachine.v2.Application.main(Application.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity.StockPrice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity.StockPrice
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:781) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

and

```
public class StockPrice  {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Ticker")
    private StockPrice stockPrice;

    private List<Double> Price;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Stock Entity you should map a Collection to your StockPrice Entity, and the relationship should be bidirectional, something like:

```
public class Stock extends AbstractEntity  {
@OneToMany(mappedBy="stock", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
/*@JoinColumn(name = "Ticker") <- Don't use this, let hibernate figure this out by the 'mappedBy' */
private List<StockPrice> Price;
(...)
```

And

```
public class StockPrice extends AbstractEntity {
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Ticker")
private StockPrice stockPrice;
```

But keep in mind that your StockPrice can't just extend your AbstractEntity, because it has a composite key

Comment: Would it be better to get rid of AbstractEntity altogether? or perhaps remove the foreign key from my sql table?

Comment: If you would like to have this relationship as OneToMany, I guess the best way is to remove the AbstractEntity, as it's sole purpose would be to define a primary key that is not entirely true to one of the entities. But this is just a matter of personal preference... Try putting a different @Id on your StockPrice, but still leaving the 'ticker' column for reference to the Stock, this is YOUR playground :)

Comment: Thanks, perhaps a stupid question, but you have set Price to be `List<StockPrice>`, what is the significance of the `<StockPrice>` part? StockPrice is obviously the entity class, but how does this relate to our list? For each ticker value there are multiple prices (and multiple of all of the other parameters), does this automatically store these in a list based on the variable name if its the same as the SQL column name?

Comment: no it won't, that's why you will need another table column to be the primary key, and ticker alone will not suffice your need, the type parameter is what will tell your ORM  to relate the two tables

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error indicates that `private double Price` needs to be a collection since it's in a @OneToMany relationship with StockPrice. You can fix this, for example, by using a List:

```
private List<Double> Price;
```

or a Set:

```
private Set<Double> Price;
```

Comment: Thanks! this fixed one of the errors but I am still receiving the following: `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn: com.stockmachine.v2.backend.entity.StockPrice.Price`

Comment: Yes, that's a different issue with your code. I suggest checking this tutorial on how to implement the mapping: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many